# Log Analytics Query Ignores ysplit

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql

I am trying to write a query and render results with multiple y axis. To achieve that I am using ysplit option for render action:

```
|render timechart with (ysplit = panels)
```

However the resulting graph ignores this. Is it known limitation of log analytics queries? Does this option work only in DataExplorer? If so is there a way how to have more y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of the `render` operators are supported in every "client" of logs.

if you look at the docs for the render operator, there's actually 2 different versions:

Azure Data Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Azure Monitor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuremonitor

You'll see that currently, `ysplit` and many other operators are not supported in the "Azure Monitor" version of the API.

(the Logs view and Workbooks view and Azure Resource Graph view all support different things.  We are *trying* to converge but is a long term process)